# What does mean_squared_error translate to in keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras

while looking at tensorflow examples online , i'm seeing this

```
xs = np.array([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], dtype=float)
ys = np.array([1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5, 3.0, 3.5], dtype=float)
model = tf.keras.Sequential([keras.layers.Dense(units=1, input_shape=[1])])
model.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss='mean_squared_error')
```

I was trying to re-write this line so that it uses objects rather than string literals

```
 model.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss='mean_squared_error')
```

So far i'm able to

```
model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.SGD(), loss='mean_squared_error')
```

For mean_squared_error we have `keras.losses.mean_squared_error(y_true, y_pred)`

I'm unable to understand y_true, y_pred and what values needs to be provided for the example above.

In summary, from example above what is equivalent of

```
loss='mean_squared_error'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to pass simply

```
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(), loss=tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError())
```

y_true and y_pred are handled automatically by keras

Comment: So i was using wrong function mean_squared_error. Thanks